why I just can capture only one value in SV layer when I use python to output?
SV values: Layer SV
:   APPID: 0x4041
    Length: 111
    Reserved 1: 0x0000 (0)
    0... .... .... .... = Simulated: False
    Reserved 2: 0x0000 (0)
    savPdu
    noASDU: 1
    seqASDU: 1 item
    ASDU
    svID: SIEMENSMU0101
    smpCnt: 983
    confRev: 1
    smpSynch: none (0)
    PhsMeas1
    value: 0
    quality: 0x00000000, validity: good, source: process
    .... .... .... .... .... .... .... ..00 = validity: good (0x0)
    .... .... .... .... .... .... .... .0.. = overflow: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .... .... 0... = out of range: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .... ...0 .... = bad reference: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .... ..0. .... = oscillatory: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .... .0.. .... = failure: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .... 0... .... = old data: False
    .... .... .... .... .... ...0 .... .... = inconsistent: False
    .... .... .... .... .... ..0. .... .... = inaccurate: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .0.. .... .... = source: process (0x0)
    .... .... .... .... .... 0... .... .... = test: False
    .... .... .... .... ...0 .... .... .... = operator blocked: False
    .... .... .... .... ..0. .... .... .... = derived: False
    value: 0
    value: 0
    value: 0
    value: 1651
    value: 0
    value: 2502
    value: 0
    quality: 0x00000000, validity: good, source: process
    quality: 0x00000000, validity: good, source: process
    quality: 0x00000000, validity: good, source: process
    quality: 0x00000000, validity: good, source: process
    quality: 0x00000000, validity: good, source: process
    quality: 0x00000000, validity: good, source: process
    quality: 0x00000000, validity: good, source: process
    .... .... .... .... .... .... .... ..00 = validity: good (0x0)
    .... .... .... .... .... .... .... ..00 = validity: good (0x0)
    .... .... .... .... .... .... .... ..00 = validity: good (0x0)
    .... .... .... .... .... .... .... ..00 = validity: good (0x0)
    .... .... .... .... .... .... .... ..00 = validity: good (0x0)
    .... .... .... .... .... .... .... ..00 = validity: good (0x0)
    .... .... .... .... .... .... .... ..00 = validity: good (0x0)
    .... .... .... .... .... .... .... .0.. = overflow: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .... .... .0.. = overflow: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .... .... .0.. = overflow: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .... .... .0.. = overflow: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .... .... .0.. = overflow: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .... .... .0.. = overflow: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .... .... .0.. = overflow: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .... .... 0... = out of range: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .... .... 0... = out of range: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .... .... 0... = out of range: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .... .... 0... = out of range: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .... .... 0... = out of range: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .... .... 0... = out of range: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .... .... 0... = out of range: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .... ...0 .... = bad reference: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .... ...0 .... = bad reference: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .... ...0 .... = bad reference: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .... ...0 .... = bad reference: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .... ...0 .... = bad reference: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .... ...0 .... = bad reference: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .... ...0 .... = bad reference: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .... ..0. .... = oscillatory: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .... ..0. .... = oscillatory: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .... ..0. .... = oscillatory: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .... ..0. .... = oscillatory: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .... ..0. .... = oscillatory: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .... ..0. .... = oscillatory: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .... ..0. .... = oscillatory: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .... .0.. .... = failure: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .... .0.. .... = failure: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .... .0.. .... = failure: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .... .0.. .... = failure: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .... .0.. .... = failure: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .... .0.. .... = failure: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .... .0.. .... = failure: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .... 0... .... = old data: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .... 0... .... = old data: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .... 0... .... = old data: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .... 0... .... = old data: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .... 0... .... = old data: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .... 0... .... = old data: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .... 0... .... = old data: False
    .... .... .... .... .... ...0 .... .... = inconsistent: False
    .... .... .... .... .... ...0 .... .... = inconsistent: False
    .... .... .... .... .... ...0 .... .... = inconsistent: False
    .... .... .... .... .... ...0 .... .... = inconsistent: False
    .... .... .... .... .... ...0 .... .... = inconsistent: False
    .... .... .... .... .... ...0 .... .... = inconsistent: False
    .... .... .... .... .... ...0 .... .... = inconsistent: False
    .... .... .... .... .... ..0. .... .... = inaccurate: False
    .... .... .... .... .... ..0. .... .... = inaccurate: False
    .... .... .... .... .... ..0. .... .... = inaccurate: False
    .... .... .... .... .... ..0. .... .... = inaccurate: False
    .... .... .... .... .... ..0. .... .... = inaccurate: False
    .... .... .... .... .... ..0. .... .... = inaccurate: False
    .... .... .... .... .... ..0. .... .... = inaccurate: False
    .... .... .... .... .... .0.. .... .... = source: process (0x0)
    .... .... .... .... .... .0.. .... .... = source: process (0x0)
    .... .... .... .... .... .0.. .... .... = source: process (0x0)
    .... .... .... .... .... .0.. .... .... = source: process (0x0)
    .... .... .... .... .... .0.. .... .... = source: process (0x0)
    .... .... .... .... .... .0.. .... .... = source: process (0x0)
    .... .... .... .... .... .0.. .... .... = source: process (0x0)
    .... .... .... .... .... 0... .... .... = test: False
    .... .... .... .... .... 0... .... .... = test: False
    .... .... .... .... .... 0... .... .... = test: False
    .... .... .... .... .... 0... .... .... = test: False
    .... .... .... .... .... 0... .... .... = test: False
    .... .... .... .... .... 0... .... .... = test: False
    .... .... .... .... .... 0... .... .... = test: False
    .... .... .... .... ...0 .... .... .... = operator blocked: False
    .... .... .... .... ...0 .... .... .... = operator blocked: False
    .... .... .... .... ...0 .... .... .... = operator blocked: False
    .... .... .... .... ...0 .... .... .... = operator blocked: False
    .... .... .... .... ...0 .... .... .... = operator blocked: False
    .... .... .... .... ...0 .... .... .... = operator blocked: False
    .... .... .... .... ...0 .... .... .... = operator blocked: False
    .... .... .... .... ..0. .... .... .... = derived: False
    .... .... .... .... ..0. .... .... .... = derived: False
    .... .... .... .... ..0. .... .... .... = derived: False
    .... .... .... .... ..0. .... .... .... = derived: False
    .... .... .... .... ..0. .... .... .... = derived: False
    .... .... .... .... ..0. .... .... .... = derived: False
    .... .... .... .... ..0. .... .... .... = derived: False

SV Layer Fields: ['appid', 'length', 'reserve1', 'reserve1_s_bit', 'reserve2', 'savpdu_element', 'noasdu', 'seqasdu', 'asdu_element', 'svid', 'smpcnt', 'confrev', 'smpsynch', '', 'meas_value', 'meas_quality', 'meas_quality_validity', 'meas_quality_overflow', 'meas_quality_outofrange', 'meas_quality_badreference', 'meas_quality_oscillatory', 'meas_quality_failure', 'meas_quality_olddata', 'meas_quality_inconsistent', 'meas_quality_inaccurate', 'meas_quality_source', 'meas_quality_test', 'meas_quality_operatorblocked', 'meas_quality_derived'

I print SV value firstly, the results like this: you can see there are 8 values in SV values, but I just can capture only first one. btw, I print packet.SV field name, I found it just show me the field of the fist value and skip other values. so I so confused, Could you help me to check it?

Generally, 8 values should be captured, but now just only one can be collected.
